# what is the detail about Reactjs list-wise diff algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, reactjs

In Reactjs official document:

List-wise diff

Problematic Case
In order to do children reconciliation, React adopts a very naive approach. It goes over both lists of children at the same time and generates a mutation whenever there's a difference.

For example if you add an element at the end:

```
renderA: <div><span>first</span></div>
renderB: <div><span>first</span><span>second</span></div>
=> [insertNode <span>second</span>]
```

Inserting an element at the beginning is problematic. React is going to see that both nodes are spans and therefore run into a mutation mode.

```
renderA: <div><span>first</span></div>
renderB: <div><span>second</span><span>first</span></div>
=> [replaceAttribute textContent 'second'], [insertNode <span>first</span>]
```

There are many algorithms that attempt to find the minimum sets of operations to transform a list of elements. Levenshtein distance can find the minimum using single element insertion, deletion and substitution in O(n^2). Even if we were to use Levenshtein, this doesn't find when a node has moved into another position and algorithms to do that have much worse complexity.

Keys
In order to solve this seemingly intractable issue, an optional attribute has been introduced. You can provide for each child a key that is going to be used to do the matching. If you specify a key, React is now able to find insertion, deletion, substitution and moves in O(n) using a hash table.

renderA: first
renderB: secondfirst
=> [insertNode second]
In practice, finding a key is not really hard. Most of the time, the element you are going to display already has a unique id. When that's not the case, you can add a new ID property to your model or hash some parts of the content to generate a key. Remember that the key only has to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique.

But what is the detail about this algorithm?